# How to test a website with Selenium when inspect element doesnt show up html code for clickable element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

I have a problem with using python Selenium on a website https://kith.com/. When it is opened for the first time it pops up question about cookies and I cannot locate the accept button using inspect element.
Tried bypassing that by importing cookies but it didnt work out.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihK0Y.png)

Comment: Add to your question the code that you've tried

Comment: well im not able to code clicking the accept button as inspect elements doesnt show html code

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to click on "Continue to shop" button initially presented there

[image]

This code does that:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

url = "https://kith.com/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-key="continueShop"]'))).click()
```

Comment: im struggling with the cookies pop-up as it doesnt show html code for this. I added image of the pop up in question

Comment: I could not see this element appearing there...